# Qt get all QLineEdits' texts within a layout

Tags: c++, qt, layout

This is simple structure I have:

```
QVBoxLayout called switchesLayout_2
 |
 |\_ QHBoxLayout
 |    |
 |    |\_ QLabel
 |     \_ QEditLine
 |
 |\_ QHBoxLayout
 |    |
 |    |\_ QLabel
 |     \_ QEditLine
and so on...
```

I need to get a text from every QEditLine in switchesLayout_2.
I've tried this code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < switchesAmount; i++) {
        req += " " + ui->switchesLayout_2->itemAt(i)->layout()->itemAt(1)->widget()->text();
    }
```

I keep getting: 'class QWidget' has no member named 'text'

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: You probably want a use `QLineEdit* pLE = qojbect_cast<QLineEdit>(ui->switchesLayout_2->itemAt(i)->layout()->itemAt(1)->widget());` to get the pointer to the QLineEdit. Then if that is not nullptr get the QString using pLE->text();

Comment: ***I keep getting: 'class QWidget' has no member named 'text'*** The compiler is correct QWidget has no text() member.

Comment: It throws 'cannot convert qlineedit to qlineedit in initialization

Comment: Okay, it works. Had to add * to QLineEdit in cast. Do i need to free memory somehow?

Comment: ***Do i need to free memory somehow*** No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `QObject::findChildren()` method on the actual parent widget.

```
const QList<QLineEdit*> lineEdits = ui->widgetThatHasSwitchesLayout_2->findChildren<QLineEdit*>();
for (QLineEdit *lineEdit : lineEdits) {
    req += " " + lineEdit->text();
}
```